# Change Android Shashlik simulator physical keyboard layout

Tags: android-emulator, languages, external-keyboard

I installed [Shashlik](http://www.shashlik.io/) an android simulator for linux. It has minimal interface. The only way to interact with it through adb.

I want to change the physical keyboard layout. currently English, I want to change the language(Not system language)